# while call function from another controller " should be compatible with "

Tags: controllers, magento2.2.6

I am trying to call function from other controller . I am using version 2.2.6 . While call it is working properly without arugument. If i send argument it provide error `should be compatible with`

**First controller**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Controller\Index;


use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ModuleFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;


class Fetchorder extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_order;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Namespace\Module\Controller\Index\Order $order
    )
{

    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    $this->_order = $order;

    return parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute($) 
{   

    $orderCollection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(array('*'));
    $orderCollection->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC');
    $orderCollection->setPageSize(10);


    foreach($orderCollection as $order)
    {

    $this->_order->getrecord($order->getId());  // without passing arugument it works.
     }
}
```

}

**Second controller**

```
<?php


namespace Namespace\Module\Controller\Index;


use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ModuleFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;


class Order extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
    protected $_categoryFactory;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
    )
{

    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;

    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getrecord($order_id = "") // without order id it call properly
{       
    echo "I am in <br/>";
}
```

}

How do i pass the arugument .

Comment: Can you please upload both file full code?

Comment: @RohanHapani , i have updated the code

Comment: Where did you add the dependency for $this->_ordercron in first controller and how are you getting the value of order id ($order->getId()), I can't see the $order object called or order loaded in your first controller file. Provide more details to help you in better and right way..

Comment: @HimmatPaliwal , i have updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use atleast `execute()` function in controller file. Without `execute()` function it will not working :

Use code like below way :

**=> Controller 1 :**

```
<?php
namespace RH\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /** @var  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    /**      * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context      */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {  
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Controller 1'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
    public function getCallFunction($param = "")
    {
        echo "Controller 1 : ".$param;
    }
}
```

**=> Controller 2 :**

```
<?php
namespace RH\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Post extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /** @var  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $_index;
    /**      * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context      */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \RH\HelloWorld\Controller\Index\Index $index
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_index = $index;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $param = "Controller 2";
        $this->_index->getCallFunction($param);
    }
}
```

Now, when you run post controller then, output be like :

> Controller 1 : Controller 2

Hope, It will helpful for you.